# Is there an easier way to assign relationships to new objects in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship

In my example, I'm trying to create a new object which has references to existing objects.  I'm finding myself having to retrieve complete objects from the database in order to reference them from my new object.

*Apologies for any small errors in the code - I'm working from memory - I don't have my code with me.*

My ViewModel contains the object itself, my two reference Ids, and a SelectList of the referenced object so I can bind to a dropdown:

```
public class GameEditViewModel
{
    public Game MyGame { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    public SelectList<Team> { get; set; }
}
```

I'm setting and getting everything perfectly fine, and the object is fully populated when I get it back, but the problem comes when I try to save this new Game:

```
public Game AddGame(GameEditViewModel gameToSave)
{
    gameToSave.MyGame.HomeTeam = 
        context.GetObjectByKey(new EntityKey(context.DefaultContainerName+".Team", "Id", gameToSave.HomeTeamId)) as Team;
    context.Attach(gameToSave.MyGame.HomeTeam);  // I think I needed this line
    gameToSave.MyGame.AwayTeam = 
        context.GetObjectByKey(new EntityKey(context.DefaultContainerName+".Team", "Id", gameToSave.AwayTeamId)) as Team;
    context.Attach(gameToSave.MyGame.AwayTeam);

    context.AddToGame(MyGame);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You see the problem here - I'm doing two extra database queries to retrieve models so I can bind to them.  Really, I should only need the Id.

If I just set the HomeTeam.Id and AwayTeam.Id properties, the context thinks I'm adding a new record and complains that all the references required for the Team object are not set.

I assume there's a better/more efficient way to do this, but I'm pretty new to EF.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't require database roundtrip:

```
gameToSave.MyGame.HomeTeamReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey(context.DefaultContainerName+".Team", "Id", gameToSave.HomeTeamId)
```

Comment: Wow, really?  Man... how did I miss that...?

Comment: @Damovisa: Sorry, but I don't know:)

Comment: I think I just assumed that it did.  I'll verify when I get home, but I'm sure you're right.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this, which is prettier imo:

```
public Game AddGame(GameEditViewModel gameToSave)
{
    gameToSave.MyGame.HomeTeam = new Team { Id = gameToSave.HomeTeamId };
    gameToSave.MyGame.AwayTeam = new Team { Id = gameToSave.AwayTeamId };

    context.AddToGame(MyGame);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```